# Relation between Noetherian Ring and Noetherian module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

My question is for an $R-$module $M$ is there any relation between $R$ being a Noetherian Ring and $M$ be a Noetherian Module?

Answer (score 7):

Over a Noetherian ring, a module is Noetherian iff it is finitely generated.

This also characterizes Noetherian rings: a ring is Noetherian iff all finitely generated modules are Noetherian.

Also, if there exists a faithful Noetherian module over a ring, then the ring is Noetherian.